# SQL Server- Sp_Blitz query executing for more than 5 hours

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-query-store, sp-blitz

I am running sp_Blitz on my SQL Server 2014 with 93 databases. It has been running for more than 5 hours and still won't complete. I am able to run  sp_BlitzWho,sp_BlitzIndex,sp_BlitzFirst and sp_Blitzbackup and they all take about 2-3 minutes to complete.

I wonder why is it (sp_Blitz) running too long and still not providing any results.

[Results for sp_blitzwho and sp_whoisactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuTfH.png)

Comment: Try the @CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 0 parameter.

Comment: Makes sense to track a long-running query, perhaps it blocked by some other process. There are plenty of ways of how to do it, for instance by using another great third party procedure: sp_whoisactive (available here: http://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: @BrentOzar, I tried CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 0 parameter. It is still taking too long and not providing any results. Please suggest if there is any other way. Please find the results for sp_blitzwho as an attachment in my post for reference. Thanks for all the guidance in advance.

Comment: @AlexanderVolok please find the results for sp_whoisactiveas an attachment in my main post for reference and please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alekhya, you need to click on session 85 column `sql_text`, this will open an actual query on a separate tab, so you can analyze it